# Does numpy.std require even spacing of the data points?

Tags: python, numpy, standard-deviation

Forgive me, I'm not as well-versed in statistics as I'd like to be, but I want to find the spread of a Gaussian-like (not exactly, but close enough) distribution of data points. When I apply numpy.std() to the array of values, I get a standard deviation that extends past the range of my x-values.

I thought my issue was that my data points are logarithmically-spaced (i.e. the x-axis is a log scale), but when I interpolated my function over evenly spaced data points I still got a strange standard deviation. Does numpy.std() require evenly spaced data points? Or is something else the problem?

Edit:

My distribution (after normalization) looks like this:

[image]

And the standard deviation if I don't interpolate it over evenly spaced sample points is 3.65, and the standard deviation if I do is 2.77. Would this be because it's so heavily weighted in the lower x-values? Do I need to edit the distribution somehow to make it more Gaussian-like for numpy.std() to work?

Comment: I think this is a statistics issue rather than about numpy. It is definately possible to get a standard dev larger than your max value - particularly if you have extreme low value outliers or small samples. 
Obviously it is also possible for your sampling to effect the standard dev: if the sampling is wider than the width of the gaussian then you'll struggle getting any meaningful stats. 
Do you want to post the array and we can take a look at the statistical reasons why?

Comment: @J.Warren I've edited the post! Thank you.